# psycopg2 control connection IP address

Tags: django, heroku, psycopg2

I'm kind of lost here. I have an app on heroku (django) that runs a script with a connection, like this:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="****", host="***", user="***", password="****")
```

The database it connects to has a firewall with a white list filled with IP addresses. The Heroku app continuosly resets the IP address so I can't know which IP psycopg2 will be using, this makes it impossible for me to effectively connect to the db. How can I set a static IP address so that psycopg2 uses that IP all the time and I can add that IP to the firewall's whitelist?. Any advice will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "set a static IP address" on Heroku, it doesn't work like that. Your project is deployed on dynos that can change location, as they do, constantly.

You either have to relax the database firewall rules, or otherwise setup some proxy machine that you control on a dedicated IP that you use to connect through to the database from Heroku or any other arbitrary location.